# VM in bridged mode, No buffer space available

Tags: linux, networking, virtual-machine, kvm

I installed KVM in ubuntu 16.04 and made a CentOS 6.8 VM on it using Virtual Machine Manager. In the network settings, I assigned bridged mode to my VM. After successful installation I assigned a static IP to CentOS. But I was unable to get the networking to work. I was unable to ping the default gateway. Moreover on my host machine ubuntu 16.04, the networking seemed to have stopped and I was unable to ping the default gateway from there as well, leaving me with the following message

ping: sendmsg: No buffer space available

After I changed the VM settings from bridged mode to NAT, I was able to ping gateway from ubuntu and the network was working fine. Can someone please explain why was I unable to ping in bridged mode, both from VM and my host?

Comment: Since you didn't mention this, do you have linked your bridge to your physical interface and put your host IP address on the bridge side? This is what I have on my Proxmox (Debian based) hypervisor and this is how bridges have to be configured. An improper bridge configuration is likely the issue. First try to put 2 VM on the bridge and see if they can ping each others.